# Rails validate that related field has a related field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these four models:

```
class Workgroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :empgroups
  has_many :employees, through: :empgroups
  has_many :workorders

class Empgroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :employee_id, :workgroup_id
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :workgroup

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :empgroups
  has_many :workgroups, through: :empgroups
  has_many :workorders

class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base        
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :workgroup
```

When a new workorder is created, I want to validate that the employee belongs to the selected workgroup.

How can I code that validation in the workorder model?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a custom validation method in the workorder model.  So it might look something like this.

```
class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base        
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :workgroup
  validate :check_employee_workgroup

  private
  def check_employee_workgroup
    errors.add(:employee_id, "Employee is not available in this work group") unless
    self.employee.workgroups.select(:id).where(id: [self.workgroup_id]).exists?         
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The need to do this may be a design issue. Perhaps you should revise your classes to look something like this:

```
class Workgroup < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :empgroups
    has_many :employees, through: :empgroups

class Empgroup < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :employee_id, :workgroup_id
    belongs_to :employee
    belongs_to :workgroup

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :empgroups
    has_many :workgroups, through: :empgroups

class Workorder < ActiveRecord::Base        
    belongs_to :empgroup
```

This way, you don't need a custom validator at all. From there, you can add in any other through: relationships necessary